# How do I know whether my Chi-square results are valid or not?

Tags: statistics, covariance, chi-squared

I've been using Qualtrics to undergo statistical analysis of two categorical variables. On such note, the cross tabulation is depicted below.
[image]

As you may see, some data points are missing, so I was wondering whether i could undergo a reliable Chi square to use in my research. When I do the Chi-square test on Qualtrics, it tells me that there is a statistically significant relationship between the two variables. It does not tell me 'Some of the cells in the table do not have enough datapoints. This result may not actually be statistically significant' which is a message that often appears if i do a chi square test on other variables that lack significant data points.

I read that sometimes, A condition of the chi-square test is that all expected counts must be greater than 5. In this case, my results would be invalid even though qualtrics doesn't state so? In other cases, i read that at least 80% of the cells should have an expected value which is higher than 5.

Do you believe that I could undergo the Chi-square test in this case ? Thank you !

Comment: Sufficient expectations are necessary because only then the chi-squared variable comes near to what it should be, multi-normal distributed. So, the test must be taken with more care, if those requirements are not met. Of course, there is no sharp definition of what is "significant". This depends on the application. Usual values are $1$ or $5$ %

Comment: Thank you . So do you believe that in this case, the results would be invalid?

Comment: There are (at least) two items to consider:  (1) Is the test statistic a reasonable measure?  That could be true even if some of the expected counts are less than 5.  (2) Does the chisquare distribution provide an adequate approximation to the distribution of the test statistic?  You could perform a bootstrap avoid having to assume that.  Finally, you might consider asking this question at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ (but stating that you've asked the same question on both forums).

Comment: And you need to ask yourself:  Is getting an answer of "Significant" or "Not significant" really going to tell you anything?  In other words, if you get an answer of "Significant", how do you plan to explain the difference?  Do you have an alternative model in mind?  Or will you just look at the numbers and make some inference?  That is another good reason to ask at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Got out my microscope to read tiny print in your table,
replicated below in R. (Row totals match your table, but
proofreading is advisable.)

```
wa = c(0,0,5,1,5,2,0)
wb = c(0,4,24,10,57,20,13)
bo = c(1,7,7,2,12,8,16)
nt = c(0,0,8,1,10,2,1)
DTA=rbind(wa,wb,bo,nt)
rowSums(DTA)
 wa  wb  bo  nt 
 13 128  53  22   # matches totals in Question
```

Then a test of independence in R *does,* quite justifiably,
give a warning message. There is only $1$ count in the first
column, so expected counts in that column cannot possibly be
large enough for the chi-squared statistic to have nearly
a chi-squared distribution.

```
cq.out = chisq.test(DTA);  cq.out

            Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  DTA
X-squared = 40.191, df = 18, p-value = 0.001966

Warning message:
In chisq.test(DTA) : 
 Chi-squared approximation may be incorrect
```

Specifically, here are the 28 expected counts. None of the expected counts in the first column is five or more (as recommended) or even three or more (as required, assuming other counts are five or more).

```
cq.out$exp
         [,1]     [,2]      [,3]      [,4]      [,5]      [,6]      [,7]
wa 0.06018519 0.662037  2.648148 0.8425926  5.055556  1.925926  1.805556
wb 0.59259259 6.518519 26.074074 8.2962963 49.777778 18.962963 17.777778
bo 0.24537037 2.699074 10.796296 3.4351852 20.611111  7.851852  7.361111
nt 0.10185185 1.120370  4.481481 1.4259259  8.555556  3.259259  3.055556
```

In such cases, R has the capability of simulating a P-value without relying
on the usual requirements for the chi-squared statistic.

```
chisq.test(DTA, simulate.p=T)

    Pearson's Chi-squared test with simulated p-value 
    (based on 2000 replicates)

data:  DTA
X-squared = 40.191, df = NA, p-value = 0.005497
```

So it does appear that web site preference and educational level are
not independent categorical variables, P-value $0.0055 < 0.05 = 5\%.$

If you cannot use software that is able to provide simulated P-values,
then I suggest you combine the first three columns to get a category 'HS or Less' and also the last two columns to get category 'Grad Deg', and then see if you have a significant result. There may still be a couple of expected scores
that are smaller than ideal, but the chi-squared approximation may be OK. (You can look at expected cell counts to see. You may want to settle for testing at the
10% level.)

If you find significance, then you can look at Pearson residuals to find which cells of
the (collapsed) table make large contributions to the significantly large
chi-squared statistic. The Pearson residual $r_{ij}$ for cell $(i,j)$ is
the (positive or negative) square root of the contribution
$c_{ij} = (X_{ij} - E_{ij})^2/E_{ij}$ (according as $X_{ij} - E_{ij}$ is positive or negative), where $X_{ij}$ and $E_{ij}$ are observed and expected cell counts, respectively. Ordinarily, Pearson residuals with largest absolute values (especially, absolute values above 1.5 or 2) point the way to
statistically significant departures from independence.

In retrospect, a power computation in advance may have pointed you toward
using about 300 subjects rather than only about 200. Also, it may have been
better not to have a category 'Both', but to force a vote for A or B. Or
to consider something like 'No Favorite' instead of 'Both' and 'Neither'. Half of the possible responses invite (busy, lazy, or nonjudgemental) subjects "permission" not to participate meaningfully in your survey. Large numbers of indecisive votes are causing a problem with analysis.

*Note:* Aside from investigating independence, it seems worthwhile noting that Website B was much more favorably scored than Website A.

```
prop.test(c(13, 128), c(141,141))

        2-sample test for equality of proportions 
        with continuity correction

data:  c(13, 128) out of c(141, 141)
X-squared = 184.34, df = 1, p-value < 2.2e-16
alternative hypothesis: two.sided
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.8902273 -0.7409784
sample estimates:
    prop 1     prop 2 
0.09219858 0.90780142
```